# doneBarButton.enabled with an && statement

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, viewcontroller

So I have a ViewController with three UITextFields. I do not want the user to be able to click done unless all three UITextFields are > 0.

This is the code I have. I do not get errors, but the Done button (barButtonItem) remains grayed out even when I have put something in each of the three UITextFields. What am I doing wrong?

```
func allTextFields(dateTextField: UITextField, numberOfLitersTextField: UITextField, costPerLiterTextField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementsString string: String) -> Bool {


    let oldText: NSString = dateTextField.text!
    let oldText2: NSString = numberOfLitersTextField.text!
    let oldText3: NSString = costPerLiterTextField.text!
    let newText: NSString = oldText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    let newText2: NSString = oldText2.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    let newText3: NSString = oldText3.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    doneBarButton.enabled = (newText.length > 0 && newText2.length > 0 && newText3.length > 0)

    return true
}
```

Comment: When are you calling this function?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `doneBarButton.enabled = ...` line and see what the value of `newText`, `newText2`, and `newText3` are.

Comment: @ZGski I have my ViewController set as UITextFieldDelegate

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something similar to this instead:

```
func validateTextFields() -> Bool {
    guard
        let dateText = dateTextField.text,
        let numberOfLitersText = numberOfLitersTextField.text,
        let costPerLiterText = costPerLiterTextField.text
        where !dateText.isEmpty && !numberOfLitersText.isEmpty && !costPerLiterText.isEmpty else { return false }
    return true
}
```

and just put this inside of the `UITextField` delegate method that I assume you are using and just call

`doneBarButton.enabled = validateTextFields()`

I think that will work how you want it to.